# How to Debug Window Service Method without attach process

Tags: windows

> How to debug Window service methods without attach process .

Answer (score 0):

```
#if (!DEBUG)
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
        { 
            new BirthdayService() 
        };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun)`#else
        // Debug code: this allows the process to run as a non-service.
        // It will kick off the service start point, but never kill it.
        // Shut down the debugger to exit
        BirthdayService service = new BirthdayService();
        service.InitializeUsersTable();
        service.GetUserAndSendMail();
        // Put a breakpoint on the following line to always catch
        // your service when it has finished its work
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
#endif
```